# Excessive 503.2 errors from https://southcentralus1-mediap.svc.ms/ when requesting thumbnails

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

We get excessive 503 errors from https://southcentralus1-mediap.svc.ms/, even when the load from our client is very low. The URL is:
https://southcentralus1-mediap.svc.ms:443/transform/thumbnail/...

> HTTP Error 503.2 - Service Unavailable
>
> The serverRuntime@appConcurrentRequestLimit setting is being exceeded.

We don't get these errors when changing the host to https:/northcentralus1-mediap.svc.ms.
Presumably, this is because the northcentral endpoint is under lighter load.

It appears that these servers are miss-configured. Can someone at MS check this out?